# Preserving decimal values in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a column from my .csv file coming in with values as 1754625.24 etc,. where as we have to save it as integer in our database. So am trying to split number with '.' and divide second part with 1000 (24/1000) as i want 3 digit number.

so i get 0.024. But i am having issues storing/preserving that value as a decimal.

I tried (DT_DECIMAL,3) conversion but i get result as '0'.

My idea is to then append '024' part to original first part. So my final result should look like **1754625024**

Please help

Comment: What if number is 1754625.4, do you want result as 175462504 (2digit) or 1754625004 (3digit). A simple solution could be, find .(dot) in the string using FINDSTRING and extract values after dot using SUBSTRING. Append zero as required and convert the resulting string into the integer format.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. First why are you dividing by 1000 to get .024 when the value is actually .24? More importantly, if you need to store it as an integer why don't you just accept the loss of precision and cast it to integer? If you truly need the values after the decimal point then store it as a data type that supports that.

Comment: And what if the whole number portion of the value ends with a sequence like 024? How do you know if those last three digits are meant to be to the left or right of the decimal point? I advise you not to do any of this and use the proper data types for the values you are trying to store. There is absolutely no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced why would you store 1754625.24 as 1754625024 when storing it as int.
But still for your case , we can use a derived column task and 
use  Replace command on the source column of csv. E.g.

```
 Replace('1754625.24','.',0)
```